# I need to convert Html to React components

Tags: html, reactjs, components

I need to convert Html to React components. So I just loaded all the necessary css files in index.html including Bootstrap and jQuery files. And just copied all html tags (of course changed "class " attribute into "className"), with the same classnames defined in CSS files. But I  can't see anything.

Comment: Please edit to fix your spelling (covert -> convert), add more detail, and either add a full stop or finish the last sentence, which looks incomplete to me.

Comment: This needs a [mcve], would you edit it to provide one?